# Can I add multiple products (http://schema.org/Product) for google structured data?

Tags: google, google-search

Can I add multiple products (http://schema.org/Product) for google structured data ?

I have multiple products in my page. Can I add all of them in a single page using multiple schema.org/Product ?

What is the guideline for adding multiple product from google ?

Comment: What is "Google structured data"?   Google uses structured data for products as described here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products